# PhoneGap html5 in iPhone

Tags: html, cordova

I have 2 html files

- login.html
- splitView.html

In **login.html**, I have written this code on button click for page navigation

```
$.mobile.changePage("splitView.html", "slideup");
```

I am able to navigate to **splitView.html** page. But the following function is not getting called on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

}
```

Please suggest me what I am doing wrong ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `$(document).ready(function(){})` in Jquery Mobile. You use `pageInit()` instead.

More info at [Jquery Mobile Docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)